# WriteableBitmap used in Mat.Mat constructor (Emgu.CV)

Tags: wpf, image-processing, emgucv, mat

what I'm trying to do is using an let say pre-loaded image within [`Emgu.CV.Mat`](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.1.0/document/html/2ec33afb-1d2b-cac1-ea60-0b4775e4574c.htm). It offers an constructor where its possible to specify a filename. But my image is already loaded (and manipulated) within the code, therefore it makes no sense to save the file here just to load it again.

I'm working within a WPF Environment and therefor have my image currently as a `WriteableBitmap`. Furthermore I found couple of hints (e.g. [here](https://github.com/neutmute/emgucv/blob/master/Emgu.CV/PInvoke/Windows.Store/ImageWindowsStore.cs)) how to convert an `Mat` to `WriteableBitmap`. But what I'm looking for is the other way round, using a `WriteableBitmap` in order to `Emgu.CV` stuff with it.

According to [Emgu CV 2.x it was possible](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Working_with_Images#Creating_image_from_Bitmap) to use a `Bitmap` but it seams that this feature was removed in Emgu CV 3.x.

Any ideas how to do it in Emgu CV Version 3?

Answer (score 0):

I have been experimenting in this area for a work related application. To effectively use a WriteableBitmap with a Mat or an Image<,> you need access to the raw pixels.

Because I have images coming from hardware as well as from creating a RenderTargetBitmap what I found works for me is to allocate a buffer using HGlobalAlloc that is the proper size and use RenderTargetBitmap.CopyPixels() to move the data to this buffer. I also create an Image using an IntPtr to this data. Once I am done with my manipulations I use a WiteableBitmap.WritePixels() to put the image back into the WriteableBitmap.

Here is also a solution from Emgu: [BitmapSourceConverter](https://sourceforge.net/p/emgucv/code/ci/master/tree/Emgu.CV.WPF/BitmapSourceConverter.cs)

Doug